# Make a php ARRAY with a PostgreSQL ARRAY, array_to_json(), json_build_array()

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql

Let me explain my problem. I manage an app that allows to give roles to Users and give them access to different schemas, with a `PostgreSQL` database.

I would like to see the details of each Users, so I it means that I want to see all the schemas + roles.

So I made a function `getList()`, that returns login+password+roles+schemas.
Here is the **function** :

```php
public static function getList()
{
    $db = DbConnect::getDb();

    $q = pg_query("SELECT
    u.usesysid as idUser, u.usename as login,
    u.passwd as password,
    ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid) WHERE m.member = r.oid) as roles,
    ARRAY(SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace pn WHERE pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'USAGE')= true AND nspname <> 'information_schema' AND nspname !~~ 'pg_%') as schemas
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u on(r.rolname=u.usename)
    WHERE usename !~ 'postgres' ORDER BY 1;");

    if ($data = pg_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        do {
            $users[] = new User($data);
        } while ($data = pg_fetch_assoc($q));
        return $users;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

BUT, (for what I understood), I need to put somewhere in my query a `array_to_json()` or `json_build_array()` or something like that because the ARRAYs in the query (`PostgreSQL`) returns a string in PHP NOT an ARRAY.

As you can see :

```php
  8 => 
    object(User)[9]
      private '_idUser' => string '24733' (length=5)
      private '_login' => string 'efefhhh' (length=7)
      private '_password' => string '********' (length=8)
      private '_roles' => string '{role1,role2}' (length=13)
      private '_schemas' => string '{schematest,public,schematest2}' (length=31)
```

So I really need a `PHP` array to make this **following** code work :

```php
$list = UserManager::getList();

foreach ($list as $elt) {
    echo '<p>' . $elt->getLogin() . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $elt->getPassword() . '</p>';

    $roles=$elt->getRoles();
    //$roles=json_decode($roles); //Will be useful if I put a array_to_json() in the query of getList ?
    if(isset($roles) && !empty($roles)){
        echo '<p>Membership of :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            echo '<li>'.$role.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    $schemas=$elt->getSchemas();
    //$schemas=json_decode($schemas); //Will be useful if I put a array_to_json() in the query of getList ?
    if(isset($schemas) && !empty($schemas)){
        echo '<p>Use schemas :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($schemas as $schema) {
            echo '<li>'.$schema.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

But I really don't know where I can put any `array_to_json()` or `json_build_array()` or anything else...
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If postgres returns you array “strings” in JSON format, then decoding that JSON should be enough already, to get workable PHP arrays. And I’d expect the most logical places for that to happen to be where you put the `//Will be useful` comments … but you commented out those json_decode calls, without any proper explanation what about this did not actually work.

Comment: Hello @04FS the post is now edited

Comment: `{role1,role2}` is not valid JSON, it would be missing quotes around those string values. Remove the leading and trailing { and }, and explode the rest at the comma …? (If any of those values itself could ever contain a comma, that would be problematic. In that case you’d need to find out how postgres encodes / masks this inside such a return values first of all then.)

Comment: Yes fine I can remove "{" & "}" and explode at the comma, but all I need is an array, even if I do that, I'll not get an array... It will always returns a string

Comment: How would exploding string with comma-separated values _at_ the comma, _not_ get you an array?

Comment: Well @04FS you were right, and, thank you so much for that, sorry I've been stuck for so long, it might be obvious to you, for real I was lost. Thank you very much, I'll post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @04FS, I didn't have to code in json. & I didn't modify my function `UserManager::getList();`.

Let me show you :

```php
$list = UserManager::getList();

foreach ($list as $elt) {
    echo '<p>' . $elt->getLogin() . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $elt->getPassword() . '</p>';

    $roles=$elt->getRoles();
    if(isset($roles) && !empty($roles) && $roles!=="{}"){
        $roles = trim($roles, "{}");
        $roles = explode (",", $roles);
        echo '<p>Membership of :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            echo '<li>'.$role.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    $schemas=$elt->getSchemas();
    if(isset($schemas) && !empty($schemas) && $schemas!=="{}"){
        $schemas = trim($schemas, "{}");
        $schemas = explode (",", $schemas);  
        echo '<p>Use schemas :</p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($schemas as $schema) {
            echo '<li>'.$schema.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```